# Grayed Out Items in Class Diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2017, class-diagram

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I have generated a class diagram by dragging an existing class onto the class diagram canvas. In the rendered diagram, all fields and some methods are grayed out. These fields and methods are used/referenced in the code, so that's not the reason they're grayed-out on the diagram. I looked at the code behind the grayed-out items, and I could not determine why certain items are grayed out. I also googled and checked the Visual Studio 2017 docs online for an explanation for these grayed-out items--to no avail.

Can anyone explain why certain elements of a class are grayed out on a Visual Studio class diagram? See this sample as a reference (note that I have other classes whose fields are not grayed out--so it's not the case that all fields are grayed out; notice that the methods Dispose and InitializeComponent are grayed out but it's not clear to me why):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> *Can anyone explain why certain elements of a class are grayed out on a Visual Studio class diagram?*

I couldn't find any documentation about it but regarding to some tests that I did, I'd say:

The class diagram designer is sensitive to `.Designer.cs` file and will render all members of the that file as grayed items, regardless of the file-nesting or access modifier.

**Example**

Create a new Form called `MyForm`, then create the class diagram and drag the form from solution explorer and drop it on the class diagram, you will see `components`, `Dispose` and `InitializeComponent` are grayed out:

[image: Class diagram gray out members of designer.cs]

Then just cut the `components`, `Dispose` and `InitializeComponent` from `MyForm.designer.cs` and paste in `MyForm.cs` and save the changes in both file. Then you see the items in back:

[image: Class diagram shows members of .cs in black]